# Disallow defining more than one instance of a class

Tags: c++, class, c++11

While ago I read about not allowing defining further instances of one object. But I cannot find that article again. Could anybody tell me how to prevent  defining any other object from class `CLog`?

```
class CLog
{
........


} log;
```

Comment: Google *Singleton pattern* and then read about why you [shouldn't be using them](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/).

Comment: @Praetorian I want to prevent defining log2 and log3 ... . Even if my program is in debug mod, do you believe I should avoid it?

Comment: Debug mode has nothing to do with your definings. Yes, Singleton is your answer %)

Comment: So, as you say, there is no directly supported way by C++?

Comment: @barej Here is what you are [looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/4371276). As for using or not using the singleton pattern, anyone who states that singleton is inherently bad is as dumb as anyone stating that singleton is the answer to everything.

Comment: @barej So don't create more than one instance then. Here's a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8337300/241631) that discusses implementing logging without use of a singleton.

Comment: Thank you @Praetorian . you made my work much easier too.

Comment: Please do not put a "solved" "tag" to your question's title. Accept an answer instead or write a new one describing what you ultimately chose.

Comment: @stefan, The answer is given in comments by Praetorian

Comment: @barej I don't care _where exactly_ the answer is. But there's one place, the answer shouldn't be: In the question.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to a singleton is to use the `Service Locator` pattern.

A good description of it and how to use it is described in http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html.

Again like the singleton this pattern should be used sparingly however a logging system can be a good use case for it and if nothing else it teaches you some new design patterns.

Answer (score -1):

Make your constructor as private.
Define one public method which returns instance of class.

```
class sample{
 private:
    sample(){};
    static *sample instance;
public:
static *sample getInstance(){
   if (instance != null)
      instance = new sample();
   return instance;
}
```

getInstance() method creates class instance before creating it checks whether the instance exists, if it exists it retuns the existing one otherwise creates new one.In this way you can make your class to create single instance of class.
As constructor is private no one can create objects using constructor.

Comment: This is not thread-safe; make the instance itself a local static.

Comment: in essence athough of course the class is not thread safe and the * is in the wrong placev and you haven't disabled copy-construction

Comment: @rubenv that is the Meyers singleton. the C++11 standard declares your construct is indeed threadsafe but destruction order is undetermined. 

call_once is a good way to go too