# Implementing logging using globals and functors

Tags: c++, logging, global-variables, functor

I want to implement C++ logging with the following characteristics:

- It must be available to all source code without needing for every function to have an extra parameter (which I presume requires a global)
- A logging call can specify a severity level (INFO, DEBUG, WARN, etc.) and the logging facility can be set at runtime to ignore calls below a certain severity level
- The log sink can be set at runtime to the console, or to a file.

Things I *don't* need are:

- Support for multiple log sinks at runtime (i.e., it all goes either to the console, or to a file)
- Support for multithreaded logging
- Ability to pass `cout`-style expressions (e.g. `"foo=" << foo`) in a logger call. I will only pass a `std::string`.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338089/522385), which appears to address my needs, but it's quite a bit over my head. I think my confusion centers around functors. (I read the Wikipedia article but it clearly hasn't sunk in.)

Here are the parts I *do* understand:

- Using a macro (e.g. LOG_DEBUG) to conveniently specify severity level and call the logger.
- Using `#ifdef NDEBUG` to keep logging calls from being compiled (although I need to be able to set logging at runtime).
- The rationale for using a macro to invoke the logger, so that it can automatically and invisibly add info like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` at point where the logger is being called.
- The LOG macro contains an expression beginning with `static_cast<std::ostringstream&>`. I *think* this is purely to do with evaluating the `cout`-style formatting string, which I don't intend to support.

Here's where I'm struggling:

```
Logger& Debug() {
  static Logger logger(Level::Debug, Console);
  return logger;
}
```

Reading about `operator()`, it looks like `class Logger` is used for creating "functors". Each Logger functor is instantiated (?) with both a level, and a LogSink. (Do you "instantiate" a functor?) LogSink is described as "a backend consuming preformatted messages", but I don't know what that would look like or how it's "written to". At what point is the static Logger object instantiated? What causes it to be instantiated?

These macro definitions...

```
#define LOG(Logger_, Message_)                   \
  Logger_(                                       \
    static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(            \
       std::ostringstream().flush() << Message_  \
    ).str(),                                     \
    __FUNCTION__,                                \
    __FILE__,                                    \
    __LINE__                                     \
  );

#define LOG_DEBUG(Message_) LOG(Debug(), Message_)
```

... and this line of code...

```
LOG_DEBUG(my_message);
```

... get preprocessed to:

```
Debug()(my_message, "my_function", "my_file", 42);
```

What happens when this executes?

How and where is the formatted string actually written to the "log sink"?

(Note: it was suggested that I look at **log4cpp** - I found it much bigger and harder to understand than what I need, not to mention the political problems I'd have bringing a third-party library into our environment)

---

UPDATE:

To understand how the above solution works, I tried writing a minimally complete, working program. I intentionally removed the following:

- the "magic" involving std::ostringstream
- the #ifdef NDEBUG
- the Logger Level class enum
- the LogSink ctor argument (for now I will just write to std::cout)

Here is the complete source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Logger {
public:
    Logger(int l);
    void operator()(std::string const& message,
                    char const* function,
                    char const* file,
                    int line);
private:
    int _level;
};

Logger::Logger(int l) :
    _level(l)
{ }

#define LOG(Logger_, Message_)  \
    Logger_(                    \
        Message_,               \
        __FUNCTION__,           \
        __FILE__,               \
        __LINE__                \
    )

#define LOG_DEBUG(Message_)     \
    LOG(                        \
        Debug(),                \
        Message_                \
    )

Logger& Debug() {
    static Logger logger(1);
    return logger;
}

// Use of Logger class begins here

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    LOG_DEBUG("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled:

```
$ c++ main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Logger::operator()(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, char const*, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-c81cf6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I see that there's no definition of a function that takes those four arguments and writes them to `std::cout`, but what is the name of the function I need to define?

(By now I agree that I should be using Boost::Log, but functors are obviously a topic that I don't fully understand.)

Answer (score 5):

The function `Debug` returns a Logger object (which is created on the first invocation of this function).

This `Logger` object seems to have `operator()()` defined for it (judging by the macro definition), which does make it *a functor*. By the way, functor is nothing special - it's by definiton any type which has `operator()()` defined for it. However, your analysis doesn't seem correct. Instead,

```
LOG_DEBUG(my_message);
```

will be expanded into

```
LOG(Debug(), Message_)
```

And that into

```
Debug()(Message_, __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Here `Debug()` will return an object which have `operator()()` defined, and this object will be used for the call.

### Some QnA

> Why doesn't the Logger& Debug() signature specify four arguments?

Because it doesn't need to. Debug() simply returns (static) Logger object created with specific arguments (log level and output device).

> At what point is the static Logger object instantiated? What causes it to be instantiated?

When Debug() function is called first time it initializes it's static objects. This is the basic of static function variables.

The last, but not the least. I personally find it not worth the efforts to write own logger. It is tedious and extremely boring unless you really need something special out of it. While I am not really crazy about both Boost.Log and log4cpp, I would (am in fact) certainly use one of them instead of rolling my own logger. Even suboptimal logging is better than spending weeks on own solution.

Comment: Where, in all of this, is my_message written anywhere?

Comment: @Chap, `Message_` is an argument to the macro `LOG_DEBUG`. When you call `LOG_DEBUG(my_message)` `Message_` is substituted with actual paramter - `my_message` in your case.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see where it's actually being outputted. Is that being done by the part that begins "static cast<...>"?

Comment: @Chap, I do not see any static_cast in the `LOG` macro. I would assume, `operator()()` for Logger object takes care of actual output.

Comment: My apologies, I was referring to the code in the SO article I referenced, which I thought was irrelevant in my case. I have edited my OP so that #define LOG is exactly like the referenced answer.

Comment: @Chap, yes, the part which begins with `static_cast...` will serialize `Message_` into temporary `std::ostringstream`, and than call `str()` - returning the string representation of `Message_` object. I am not clear why it has `flush()` or cast in it, though.

Comment: So as I thought, it's not relevant to my problem - one way or another, we've got this nicely formatted string, but nowhere is it actually outputted or sent to the "LogSink". I guess the referenced answer didn't attempt to describe that.

Comment: @Chap, I would not follow this answer. The overall quality of this solution is low. For example, when Message_ is a string, the code will unneccessary send it to stringstream, resulting in performance degaradation.